# Is it possible to customise firebase email templates

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to customise firebase email templates at html level. In my dashboard the field seems to be there

[image]

But is not editable. I am using their free tier at the moment, will this become editable if I upgrade to paid plan? Can I request this field to become editable somehow?

Right now setting up deep/universal links results in a really really long bad looking url sent to user, it would be great if it could be custumised i.e. put under certain button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the three email templates:

1. Email password verification
2. password reset
3. email address change

Password reset, text can be changed please see the image below:

[image: Password reset]

The other two options, the text cannot be changed to prevent spam (as it says if you hover the mouse on the question mark)